# Как сделать заливку текста изображением с анимацией?

Tags: html, css, css3, анимация, css-animation

Как сделать заливку текста изображением с анимацией?

Comment: киньте описание хорошее чтобы понять что Вам надо.

Comment: ну я хз как объяснить, но на ютабе было видео с этим эффектом

Comment: @Leks наверное, можно сказать текстура текста - это фото. Но есть фишка, чтобы эта текстура двигалась

Comment: @Sevastopol' ну примеров не видел, но как объяснить понятия не имею, извиняюсь

Comment: @Sevastopol' Да! Именно. Только надо чтобы она бесконечно повторялась, двигалась и двигалась.

Comment: @sevastopol' спасибочки :3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как пример:

```css
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 900;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20vw;
  line-height: 90vh;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  background: url('https://img3.goodfon.ru/original/2200x1467/9/63/abstract-colors-background-3618.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top left;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  animation: background 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes background {
  0% {
    background-position: top left;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: bottom right;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Stack</h1>
```

Comment: ДА именно то, спасибо Вам

Comment: и вопрос, что именно отвечает за то, что у текста фон? background-clip: transparent; ?

Comment: шмякнул на галочку)

Comment: Вам тоже успехов!

Comment: [криво только у меня отображается ?](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pgws2ufaib8lrx6/bugs%20css3.mp4?dl=0) или нет ?

Comment: @MaximLensky поменяйте скорость анимации будет плавнее, у меня из-за скорлсти отображалось фиг знает как

Comment: @Tripletree какую ещё скорость поменять ? я смотрел то что в сниппете

Comment: а что криво отображается то?

Comment: @Sevastopol' так я же про то что в полноэкранном режиме нету это слова а просто движущийся фон

Comment: @Sevastopol' я же врач ..дежурю ...браузер: firefox самый последний

Comment: @Sevastopol' так вроде бы у нас тихо - а людей с подозрением привозят ....кого то отпускают а кто то остаётся ...я не инфекционист но дежурить заставляют ..временный профиль есть ...